# OpenId connect (OAuth 2): How does look the flow when Resource Owner is not the end user (SSO)?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I would like to provide some standarized SSO mechanism in my application (some different clients, growing number of services in the backend). I am wondering if OIDC/OAuth 2 is the right tool for it. 
In all examples I have seen, end user is the Resource Owner and it grants permissions (or not) to some external apps by redidericting to a page asking for permissions. 
My use case is different, I want to use OAuth inside my system (for apis, web pages etc.): resource owner is i.e. some service with database (plus administrator who have access to it), end user tries to get some resources from the system. User cannot grant anything, he can be granted. I think it's the most classic scenario, which can be named Single-Sign-On. Is there any standard flow for this in OAuth 2 (or preferably OpenId Connect)? Is it achievable? Or am I looking at a wrong tool?

Answer (score 2):

OIDC/OAuth can be used for both consumer as well as enterprise scenario's. The consent steps of OAuth are useful in consumer oriented scenario's. When dealing with enterprise scenario's like yours, there's no point in asking consent since it is implicit, at least for the enterprise's apps. That is certainly covered by OAuth/OIDC: the Authorization Server is not required to ask for consent and can (typically) be configured to skip that step for particular Clients. So: using OpenID Connect without consent would be suitable.

Comment: Can you point out any examples/tutorials of this type of scenario in OIDC. Do you have any knowledge is it easily achievable with IdentityServer?

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase you can use combination of OpenID Connect and OAuth Client_Creds flow. For example suppose you have a HRMS application which needs to get the employee data to show to the employee from some DB.

1. Register HRMS with OPenID Provider
2. Register HRMS as Client to OAuth Server (OpenID Server and OAuth Server can be same)
3. When User comes to HRMS application:

   a. Check for Id_token cookie, if not present then redirect to IDP

   b. IDP authenticates and if successful redirects back to SP with ID token

   c. If token is valid then SP sets the token as cookie in the browser using another redirect to itself but to the home page
4. Now All processing will be server side:
   a. HRMS app hits the IDP to get the User Data

   b. If successful then it hits the OAuth Server to get the access_token

   c. if successful then it uses the access_token to talk to DB Service and
   get the data

SP=Service Provider, IDP = Identity Provider
Actual flow can be a little different based on security considerations.
Hope this makes it helps.